# Resize /system partition on Galaxy note 3 SM-N9005

Tags: adb, custom-roms, partitions, system, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I am trying to resize the partition `/system` using the `parted` and `gdisk` commands. But none of these commands succeed in changing `mmcblk0` partitions after execution.
The things I do are as follows:

- install adb and fastboot and put them to the system variables.
- enable Settings>developer options>USB debugging and Root debugging
- install TWRP recovery.
- run cmd in adminitsrator permission.
- write these command in CMD :

```
    adb root  
    adb reboot recovery  
    adb push gdisk /sbin  
    adb push parted /sbin  
    adb shell chmod 777 /sbin/gdisk  
    adb shell chmod 777 /sbin/parted  
    adb shell  
    ~#> cd /dev/block  
    dev/block> gdisk mmcblk0  
    Partition table scan:  
      MBR: protective  
      BSD: not present  
      APM: not present  
      GPT: present  
    Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.  
    
    Command (? for help): p  
    Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 61071360 sectors, 29.1 GiB  
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes  
    Disk identifier (GUID): 98101B32-BBE2-4BF2-A06E-2BB33D000C20  
    Partition table holds up to 128 entries  
    Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33  
    First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 61071326  
    Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries  
    Total free space is 8158 sectors (4.0 MiB)  
    
   

     Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name  
           1            8192           38911   15.0 MiB    8300  apnhlos  
           2           38912          156543   57.4 MiB    0700  modem  
           3          156544          157567   512.0 KiB   FFFF  sbl1  
           4          157568          157631   32.0 KiB    FFFF  dbi  
           5          157632          157695   32.0 KiB    FFFF  ddr  
           6          157696          161791   2.0 MiB     FFFF  aboot  
           7          161792          162815   512.0 KiB   FFFF  rpm  
           8          162816          163839   512.0 KiB   FFFF  tz  
           9          163840          184319   10.0 MiB    FFFF  pad  
          10          184320          204799   10.0 MiB    8300  param  
          11          204800          233471   14.0 MiB    8300  efs  
          12          233472          239615   3.0 MiB     FFFF  modemst1  
          13          239616          245759   3.0 MiB     FFFF  modemst2  
          14          245760          268287   11.0 MiB    FFFF  boot  
          15          268288          294911   13.0 MiB    FFFF  recovery  
          16          294912          321535   13.0 MiB    FFFF  fota  
          17          321536          335853   7.0 MiB     8300  backup  
          18          335854          341997   3.0 MiB     FFFF  fsg  
          19          341998          341999   1024 bytes  FFFF  fsc  
          20          342000          342015   8.0 KiB     FFFF  ssd  
          21          342016          358399   8.0 MiB     8300  persist  
          22          358400          376831   9.0 MiB     8300  persdata  
          23          376832         5095423   2.3 GiB     8300  system  
          24         5095424         5709823   300.0 MiB   8300  cache  
          25         5709824         5730303   10.0 MiB    8300  hidden  
          26         5730304        61071326   26.4 GiB    8300  userdata  
    
    Command (? for help): d  
    Partition number (1-26): 26  
    
    Command (? for help):w
```

(curser blinking) and device goes to hang!!!!!

anyone can help me? I do this in `parted` command. It is like above.
after restarting the device, all of the partition are there, like before...

Comment: do yourself a favor and don't try this on device. make a dump of mmcblk0 and do some dry run on this file instead

Comment: I backed up from cash,system,modem... in TWRP. Thank you for your inform.

Comment: what i mean you should do parted on the backup, not on the device itself. you can very easy brick your device https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218269

Comment: I really appreciate. you opened my eyes...

Comment: @elbarna would you please take a look at my question?

Comment: I think the bootloader of device is lock. Unfortunately I can not connect to fastboot, because of using windows 10 x64 but in developer option `OEM Unlock` is missing. Also, I used different PIT file to repartition the device, but Odin return error `RQT_CLOSE!!`.

Comment: Thank you @alecxs. If my device is locked, then how do I flashed Lineageos on it?

Comment: i didn't noticed you already unlocked bootloader because i didn't know you are talking about LineageOS. Anyway some protections live in aboot (bootloader) but afaik LineageOS comes with boot (kernel) only. therefore it might still be true (or why should LineageOS hide the OEM unlock feature from developer options)!? can't you see KG/RMM prenormal state on download mode screen?

Comment: Thank you @alecxs for replying. I think the KG/RMM lock is for devices made in 2017 and beyond. anyway, there are some text line on the bootloader screen that are as follows: `ODIN MODE
PRODUCT NAME: SM-N9005
CURRENT BINARY: Custom
SYSTEM STATUS: Custom
REACTIVATION LOCK: OFF
KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 0x1 (2)
QUALCOM SECUREBOOT: ENABLE (CSB)
RP SWREV: S2, T2, R2, A3, P3
SECURE DOWNLOAD : ENABLE
UDC START`

Comment: what about my suggestion dry run offline on mmcblk0 backup? there is cgdisk or sgdisk left you can try. afaik LineageOS provides flashable zip for resizing. if nothing works you still can update EBR with hex editor (there exist tools on xda). Disclaimer: all of this not recommend/at own risk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: how to increase system partition and decrease data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216123/android-how-to-increase-system-partition-and-decrease-data-partition)

Comment: thank you @alecxs.  I tried cgdisk but this command isn't on /sbin, tried to resizing with sgdisk but this command did same as gdisk and parted too, nothing change finaly. I can't find lineageOS resizing flashable zip on net. And about EBR, I tried to find out how can I do that! I searched and read many forum, this is for Mediatek devices however samsung hlte is not mediatek.

Comment: i did manually on GT-I9301i but can't remember which tool used. you must be right because Partition Editor is for MTK. maybe it was PIT Magic

Comment: read [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-official-11-lineageos-18-1-for-samsung-galaxy-note-3-hlte.4267527) or ask in [Libera](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hlte/install) Chat for hints. *flo-deb_clamor_repartition.zip* is such example for other device (don't try!)

Comment: I used PIT Magic too, with many PIT files that downloaded from XDA even I edited a PIT file by myself.  when I want to write it to the device, Odin shown this error: `RQT_CLOSE!`. I have read that forum you suggested, there is nothing for repartition. Thank you @alecxs for your try, but your comments not the solution of my problem.

Comment: Sorry for misleading. Nevertheless you could ask in that forum too. try heimdall flash tool instead Odin