# How do I create a separate vendor partition?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, treble

I recently got an android phone running AOSP Android 5.1 Lollipop. I want to upgrade its software to higher android version, probably 9.0 as per the phone's capacity. But for that, I need treble support in the phone. And for that, I need to create a vendor partition. Here is a tutorial I found on XDA.
[Link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-project-treble-manual-create-vendor-partition-for-pt-gsi-rom-mi3-mi4.3878995/)

This guide is focused on MI3/MI4 devices and the resource ROM mentioned in it is also for MI3/MI4 devices. I think they may not work on my phone. The phone with me is of Micromax Canvas model. So please guide me through this. Thanks.

Comment: You can't make a device support treble by simply creating a vendor partition. Better search for the newest custom ROM for your device and use that.

Comment: No new ROM available for this model. But even if I can't support treble by creating a vendor partition, please tell me how to create a vendor partition. And if the above method is applicable for other devices too.

Comment: Please read including all comments. Working on the partition table is the easiest way to brick your device: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237263/resize-system-partition-on-galaxy-note-3-sm-n9005

Comment: Looks serious. Thanks for all these resources. I will try my best not to do it.

Comment: Use `parted` or `gdisk` (or its variant) tools to create partition as you would do on any Linux system. Here's a quick example to use `sgdisk`: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220042/218526. Bear in mind that any such command could be the last communication you've with your device. Partitioning is something which must be done when you know what you are doing, not by copying commands from support forums.

Comment: Thanks for the information Irfan Latif. I know that wrong partitioning can be the worst nightmare for a person with a phone. But, I still wish to try it out on my experiment phone as I have its stock rom and flash tool to restore original os if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Be aware that stock ROM and flash tool might not be enough to restore a device bricked due to partitioning went wrong: [Can I flash Android on device with overwritten mmcblk0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218346/218526).