# adb sideload stuck at 36%

Tags: twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-2, lineageos, side-loading

I am struggling to flash lineage-14.1-20181216-nightly-i9100-signed.zip , on a old S2

the installation gets stuck both with `adb sideload` and manual 'install' on TWRP, with message on phone logs
`patching system image unconditionally`

I tried `heimdall flash`, following [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/5yvv35/comment/detxpao/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) but I get the error:
`ERROR: Protocol initialisation failed!`

any idea?

thanks

ps: also, `fastboot` does not see any device

Comment: it might be a system partition size ... (?) given that on phone it's 503 MB, while the whole LOS folder is 561 MB  ...

Comment: maybe this could help ? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216123/android-how-to-increase-system-partition-and-decrease-data-partition

Comment: actually I try the steps recommended there, but I get `adb: error: cannot stat parted: No such file or directory`

Comment: Based on the Reddit thread, I think you're right that the system partition is too small. Samsung is a bit different than other manufacturers, so I'm not sure `parted` may work. Btw, I read [the continuation on that Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/5yvv35/patching_system_image_unconditionally/deuhvdb/) where they successfully repartitioned using `heimdall` and correct PIT file. Have you tried that instead?

Comment: thanks! I think I managed to install it, by looking at the charging logo ... but the OS  still does not start :/ https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unofficial-11-0-0-r43-i9100-lineageos-18-1.4199759/post-86209793

Comment: although,  not lineageOS 18, but the 14, taken from https://lineageosroms.com/i9100/

Comment: lineageos rely on stock firmware. flashing in repartitioning mode, PIT is rewritten therefore **all** partitions get lost (except overlapping old PIT entries by coincidence maybe)

Comment: yeah, although,  right now it's stuck on boot-loop  -- checking this further